# Does Flink sql support allowedLateness in sql query now?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-sql

How can I apply allowedLateness in this query?

```
select FIRST_VALUE(uid) as uid, mid, count(1) as c from table(TUMBLE(TABLE table_name, DESCRIPTOR(ts), INTERVAL '3' MINUTES)) where target = true group by mid;
```

I searched a lot from flink document and google, but nothing useful. So can anyone tell me does Flink sql support allowedLateness of window function in sql query now?

Comment: No, this is not supported.